# How to set the same ToolBar in different activities if I don't want to paste the same code?

Tags: java, android, mobile-development

I used AppBarLayout & ToolBar to replace the default ActionBar. I have six activities which are supposed to use my custom ActionBar. But I don't want to paste the same code in onCreate() function for each activity. 
How can I do the same settings just for once?  I am new to Android, thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe you can use Fragments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this solution:

1. MyBaseActivity:

   ```
   public class MyBaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   // do not override onCreate here..

   protected void setContentViewAndSetUpToolBar(int layoutResID) {

   setContentView(layoutResID);

   // SetUpToolBar Code Here.
   }
   // menu callbacks Overrides here.
   }
   ```
2. OtherActivity:

   ```
   public class OtherActivity extends MyBaseActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       super.setContentViewAndSetUpToolBar(R.layout.layout_for_activity);
       //..
   }
   //..
   }
   ```

Comment: I’ve thought about using parent activity and child activity. Since BaseActivity has set its own layout file, how should I edit child activities’ layout file? Would parent activity’s layout be inherited as well?

Comment: hi elm, parent activity has a method "setContentViewAndSetUpToolBar" you can call it from onCreate callback in your child activity. so in your child activity you dont call setContentView, you just pass your layout as param.. and setContentView will be called in parent.

Comment: you can't set layout in both. if you overried onCreate in child class and call setContentView inside'it every thing will be overriden.

Answer (score 1):

You could use one Activity. And a bunch of Fragments.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try it. If problem exists I will ask you again:)